# DotNetNuke Short Summery

Tags: dotnetnuke

I need a page that displays a short summery of text from other pages.
If anybody know how this is made please help

Thanks
Best Regards
Mats

Comment: Can you please provide more details? What type of content is it? How should this content be managed? How does the user interact with it?

Comment: I have a page which needs to display a short summery of a full article, the page i have now i need to first make a text/html module for the summery then make a child of the page and write the full story.
It would be nice if it just made the short summery on the main page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the circumstances are but a product such as [News Articles](http://www.ventrian.com/Products/Modules/NewsArticles.aspx) might do what you want. Or possibly [RSS](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Extensions-Forge/Module-News-Feeds.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[Efficion's Whats New module](http://www.efficionconsulting.com/dotnetnuke/modules/whats-new) might do what you need. It would only work for modules that support the ISearchable interface.